# Are AMEX cards accepted in Universal Studios JPN & Pokemon Centers? Is the JCB/AMEX partnership applicable anywhere?

Tags: japan, payment-cards, tokyo, osaka

I'm traveling to Japan in the next few months and wanted to know if these two locations accept American Express credit cards.

I also saw that JCB has a partnership with AMEX but information is scarce. Does anyone know if an establishment accepts JCB it will also accept AMEX?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JCB has a partnership with AMEX so you will be fine. There are some Japanese articles about this

[Announcement for user](https://news.cardmics.com/entry/amex-tukaeru-shiharai/)

```
カードが使える場所＝JCBが使える＝アメックスも使える. 
Card usable: JCB usable = AMEX usable
```

[Announcement for member stores](https://www.woshiru.com/creditcard/card/amex/jcb_kameiten_amex.html)

```
アメックス社はJCBと加盟店開放契約を結んでいるため、国内にあるほとんどのJCB加盟店ではアメックスカードを利用可能です。 
Since AMEX and JCB have a contract, AMEX is acceptable for almost JCB member stores
```

2 places you will visit accept VISA/MASTER/JCB so they will accept AMEX.
Universal Studio and Pokemon Center also have notes in English about credit cards

[Pokemon center](https://centraltokyo-tourism.com/en/spot/detail/100302035)

```
Credit cards    AMEX・VISA ・Master ・DC ・JCB ・UnionPay
```

[Universal Studio](https://www.usj.co.jp/e/parkguide/)

```
VISA, JCB, MasterCard and AEON Card credit cards and China UnionPay cash card are accepted at selected facilities within the park.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I've noticed that people on TripAdvisor say that USJ does not accept AMEX although I did eventually find that there's even a partnership between USJ/AMEX asking to actually use the cards in the park.

Comment: I hope that there's no issue whatsoever and we get to use the AMEX cards without hassle. Any further information you might find is amazing and I can't thank you enough for this.

Comment: As what stating in USJ site, there is even a `special ticket` for AMEX owner. http://www.usj.co.jp/ticket/partner/amex-royal.html. A quick Google Translate would give you fate that `This ticket is for American Express card members only.  While purchasing, please be sure to use the American Express card.` And even if issues happen, you can always withdraw cash from almost every ATM at convenience stores such as 7-Eleven, Family Mart etc. Look for the AMEX signs

Comment: Thank you Binh! I did read somewhere that there was now a USJ/AMEX partnership for using the cards inside the park. Hope this is true! Thank you!